# What is the hotspot offset?

Tags: java, worldwind

When I'm trying to add a label to a [TacticalSymbol](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.4/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/symbology/AbstractTacticalSymbol.html#addLabel%28gov.nasa.worldwind.render.DrawContext,%20gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Offset,%20gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Offset,%20java.lang.String%29) in Worldwind, it has an Offset field for the offset of the label, and a second Offset field for a hotspot.  What does this hotspot offset do?  How does it affect the label positioning?

Here is the relevant api:

```
addLabel(DrawContext dc, Offset offset, Offset hotspot, String modifierText)
```

Comment: would the close voters please clarify what part of my question is unclear?

Comment: You might want to add a link: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own `TacticalSymbol` ?

Comment: @zakinster yes, I'm trying to adjust the offsets for the label positions.  Since they are all hard coded in I have to implement my own version.

Comment: When in doubt, look at the [source](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/symbology/AbstractTacticalSymbol.java).